# R function not returning any value when creating dynamically dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to create dynamic dataframe and it work perfectly with this piece of code :
TypeSite Contain 4 value which is irrelevant, this will create y different dataframe named after the level and copy only the data assigned to this dataframe in it.

```
z = levels(TypeSite)

for (i in z) {
  assign(paste0(i), data.frame(airBC2[airBC2$TypeSite == i,]))
}
```

But when I try to create a function with it it doesn't work R give me no error but it does not show anything in the console.

```
myfunction = function(x,columnName)
{
  z = levels(x$column)
  for (i in z) {
    assign(paste0(i), data.frame(x[x$columnName == i,]))
  } 
}


myfunction(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that it would show you something in the console. That's not what `assign` does.

However, we can modify it like this:

```
data(iris)

TypeSite      <- iris$Species
iris$TypeSite <- TypeSite

z = levels(TypeSite)

for (i in z) {
  assign(paste0(i), data.frame(iris[iris$TypeSite == i,]))
  print(paste0("Dear binsbins2001, I have just created a data.frame called ", i, ". Love, The Console"))
}
```

The console output is:

> ```
> [1] "Dear binsbins2001, I have just created a data.frame called setosa. Love, The Console"
> [1] "Dear binsbins2001, I have just created a data.frame called versicolor. Love, The Console"
> [1] "Dear binsbins2001, I have just created a data.frame called virginica. Love, The Console"
> ```

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough, my for loop was creating dataframe, but when I insert the loop in a simple function the function does not create the dataframe anymore

Comment: assign(paste0(i),data.frame(iris[iris$TypeSite == i,])), envir = .GlobalEnv)
envir = .GlobalEnv
this what was missing to print in the global environment of R studio